# GhostScript Printer driver pdf -> ps-> PDF searchable

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript, searchable

I have an issue where I have a custom virtual printer that takes a ps file and then converts it to a PDF

Here is the code and options

```
 gvi = new GhostscriptVersionInfo(sDLLPath);
              //proc = new Ghostscript.NET.Processor.GhostscriptProcessor(gvi);
             List<string> switches = new List<string>();
            String outName = "PrintedDocument.pdf";
            switches.Add("-q");
            switches.Add("-sDEVICE=pdfwrite");
            switches.Add("-dBATCH");
          //  switches.Add("-dNOPAUSE");
          //  switches.Add("-dNOPROMPT");
            switches.Add(@"-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress");
            switches.Add("-dHaveTrueTypes=true");
            switches.Add("-dEmbedAllFonts=true");
            switches.Add("-dSubsetFonts=false");
         //   switches.Add("-c \".setpdfwrite <</NeverEmbed [ ]>> setdistillerparams\"");
            switches.Add(@"-o" + outName);
            switches.Add("-f" +psFilename );
```

The issue is if I print a PDF that is perfectly good, since my printer driver only sees the postscript when it converts that pdf ps file back to pdf I lose all search capabilities.  Are there any flags or anything else I can do for this since I do not have a way to catch the file name and determine if it was a pdf prior to printing.  In an ideal world I'd just be able to look at the file name prior to converting to postscript but I do not have this option as the virtual printer driver is nothing more than a mappped printer port to drop the ps in.

Comment: Without seeing your original PostScript file its impossible to comment. You also seem to be going PDF->PS->PDF, why ? Every time you go round that path you run the risk of losing information **especially** if you go via a printer driver. You also haven't said which version of Ghostscript you are using, nor which operating system, though it sounds like Windows.

Comment: I am not sure if you read my post.  I specifically state why I am going from pdf ps pdf.  It is a virtual printer driver where all things printed go to postscript.   Also I provided enough information, take any searchable pdf print it to postscript anyway you want, I created a printer for this, then use the code I provided in Ghostscript.  The outcome will be a non searchable pdf.   This is true with most pdf printers (i.e. Fox it, Adobe, etc). Converting pdf to ps to pdf is causing the output to not be searchable... I am trying to see if that's avoidable.  Any version of gs gives same result.

Comment: Yes, I did read your post, but it didn't really answer the question. If you want a PDF, and you have a PDF, why send it to a virtual printer to create a PDF ? As regards providing the information, it is **you** who are requesting help, you need to make it easy for people to help you. I'm not going to create a PostScript printer on FILE, find a suitable PDF file, etc, etc.Note that you are **NOT** 'converting PDF to PostScript' when if you print the PDF file to a Windows printer driver. You are creating a PostScript program, whose **sole** target is a visual representation, for printing.

Comment: I just get frustrated when the comment is just to tell all the things I do wrong...  Let's break it down...  Why am I going to ps, well I don't know how else to explain it but a universal ps virtual printer does not care what type of file you start with, and as I stated I'd love to have the option to catch the file before it was converted  to ps, but I have never seen a program independent virtual printer that would allow you to bypass the the ps.  The driver grabs the output and works from there which is a must... Now this information really doesn't help.  Second if you can't convert a (cont)

Comment: Pdf to ps in seconds using any method you want or you are not already familiar with Ghostscript then this post is likely not for you.  I am genuinely not trying to be rude, I just see many people post why they can't answer citing reasons not relevant to why you really can't.  I apprieciate if you were really trying to help, but that is not how your original response came off to me.

Comment: I am the developer responsible for the PostScript to PDF conversion of Ghostscript, so yes, I think I could reasonably claim to be familiar with Ghostscript. I still don't understand why you want to do what you are attempting, but we can leave that to one side. My reason for wanting to understand is that this can enormously improve my ability to help. So, if you would like to post an example, I will look at it. Of course it all depends very largely on what application you are using to print the PDF, the PostScript printer driver and of course the operating system.

Comment: gswin32c.exe ^
  -dNOPAUSE ^ 
  -dBATCH ^
  -sDEVICE=pswrite ^
  -sOutputFile=mydocument.ps ^
   mydocument.pdf

Comment: Now the question is simple anyway to turn that ps file to a SEARCHABLE PDF.  Again pretend I don't know how that ps file is created.  The answer might simply be that there is no way to do it with just the post script...

Comment: I was hoping there was/is a flag i could put on my ps to pdf conversion that would allow me to not lose the search capabilities, but that may be wishful thinking and that text is lost as soon as it gets converted.

Comment: Most files that get converted to pdf using -sDEVICE=pdfwrite convert to a serachable PDF (WORD, EXCEL, NotePAD, etC).  a PDF however loses search capabilities... I don't know why as it seems like it should exist.  I tried different apps (Acrobat, Foxit, etc) all create a virtually identical ps file that I can not gs to convert to a pdf that contains the document text.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Well I'm sorry that I'm apparently wasting your time. I already offered to drop the subject of why you are doing this but you seem keen to harp on it.  You don't seem to get it either, I'm not going to go to any great effort to help you, especially given the nature of the comments you are making. I'm not going to install printer drivers or anything, if you want help then you need to make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: If you can give me a PostScript file then I'll look at it. If you can't then I'm afraid there is nothing I can do to help you. NB you still haven't said what Operating System you are using, though I'm assuming Windows, and you haven't said what version of that. And it matters because the print pipeline differs markedly on different versions of Windows.

Comment: Why you couldn't spend 5 seconds, but could spend 2 minutes writing a comment.  FYI: the solution is ridiculously cool too:)

Comment: And you aren't going to post it for the edificatio0n of others ? Well I guess that attitude fits in with the rest of your comments.

Comment: I contribute to many boards... Probably over 20k posts resolving issues for other people using 20+ programming languages...  Your comments were all about how I didn't know how to post and was a "NB" (Your words not mine).  Then rather than take a good look at the question and see my point that there was sufficient info... You chose not to re-evaluate stretching for every reason you could not answer.  That is why I don't want to help the gs expert... I help many people often...  I help people bc I like helping to genuinely help, not talk down to them as your attitude comes off to me.

Comment: Interesting take. I just reviewed my comments and its not me using the personal epithets. I'm sorry that you feel I was condescending, I certainly didn't intend that. I would say that your own attitude could use some revision though. However this conversation is clearly going nowhere, and you obviously don't intend to contribute your own solution (assuming it exists), so I guess we should just leave this here. I won't bother to comment further on this thread.

Comment: Oh dear, I think I finally understand at least some of the source of Vinnie's ire. It seems he has taken offence at my use of 'NB' and thinks I'm calling him a 'noob'. Of course what I really meant was an abbreviation for 'Nota Bene' which is Latin for note well, eg http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=NB Well, probably too late to correct that now I guess. Maybe Vinnie will read this, and it will help prevent future misunderstandings.